# Curl not able to Connect to host while Curl is enabled on Server

Tags: php, web-services, curl, localhost

I am calling a webservice using curl, it is working fine in localhost but when I use the same script on my live website to call it outputs the error:

> Couldn't connect to host

Here are my Live website curl settings
[image]

```
 $soap_request = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
    <InsertData xmlns="http://exampleServiceSite:6265">          
      <remarks>No Remarks</remarks>
      <insuranceValue>0</insuranceValue>
    </InsertData>
    </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';

$header = array(
    "POST /Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1",
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"http://exampleServiceSite:6265/InsertData\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
    );

    $soap_do = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL,            "http://exampleServiceSite:6265/" );
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
        curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
        $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
        var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Do you need to set a proxy? Is the port 6265 open ?

Comment: @David the webservice I wish to consume is from 3rd party, So I cannot check port of that third party webservice, Or do you mean I need to check port 6265 on my live webserver ?

Comment: Port 6265 needs to be open on both sides. What if you change the url to be http://google.com? Do you still get a could not connect to host? If yes, try setting up curl proxy.

Comment: @David with google.com it works fine, i.e. doesn't give any error just load the google.com page

Comment: Then, if the host of the 3rd party's web service is correct, it's probably a problem of the port 6265 not being open on your live server

Comment: @David Yes 3rd party's web service host is correct, How can I open port 6265 from my live server ? I just have access to cpanel and what if I use php's native SoapClient ? do I need to open port 6265 on my live server for that SoapClient too?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. Changes are that only traditional ports are allowed. Check with the server's support team

Comment: Okay, I have sent them email, but I don't understand why I need to open port 6265 on my webserver ? what if I want to use 50 third party webservices that have 50 different ports, that means I need to open same 50 ports on my server too,

Comment: Check the firewall settings in cpanel.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SSH access to your dev machine?

If so open an SSH session and try this:

`>telnet exampleServiceSite 6265`

do you get something like this come up?

```
Trying 62.253.72.158...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: You could try to `curl` from the command line too, this might reveal more info than `telnet`: `curl -v http://server:6265`

Comment: don't have access to SSH , its shared hosting with limited cpanel access